# Move pointers in order to print in a different order

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, ansi-c

I have to complete this program.

I've a file like that

```
Name iD Num_of_elements elem(1) elem(2), ... , elem(n)
james 1 3 AAA BBB CCC
arthur 2 2 EEE FFF
james 1 1 KKK
irine 3 4 EEE FFF DDD AAA
james 1 1 XXX
```

I need to create a list, load the file into the list and print it ordering it as follow:

```
james 1 3 AAA BBB CCC
james 1 1 XXX
james 1 1 KKK
arthur 2 2 EEE FFF
irine 3 4 EEE FFF DDD AAA
```

(it's necessary to print persons with the same iD before, then the others).

I've created part of program in ANSI C, but I'm not able to complete the "final function" as request.

void printListOrderedByiD(struct list *top)
{ }

That's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define len 35

struct elements
{
    char name[len];
};

struct list
{
    char name[len];
    int id;
    int numOfElements;
    struct elements *pElements; /* pointer to the struct elements */
    struct list *next;
};


FILE *openFile(FILE *fp)
{
    fp=fopen("file.txt", "r");
        if (fp==NULL)
            {
                perror("");
                exit(1);
            }
    return (fp);
}


struct list *newNode(FILE *fp)
{
    int i=0;
    struct list *temp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    fscanf(fp, "%s\t%d\t%d\t", temp->name, &temp->id, &temp->numOfElements);

    temp->pElements=(struct elements *)malloc(temp->numOfElements*sizeof(struct elements));

        for (i=0; i<temp->numOfElements; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s\t", temp->pElements[i].name);
        }

        temp->next=NULL;

    return temp;
}

struct list *insertAsLast(struct list *top, FILE *fp) /* this function will insert every node at the end of the list */
{
    if (top==NULL)
    {
        top=newNode(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        top->next=insertAsLast(top->next, fp);
    }

return top;
}

void printList(struct list *top) /* this procedure will stamp the list as loades from the file */
{
    int i=0;

    if (top==NULL)
    {
        printf("//\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s %d %d ", top->name, top->id, top->numOfElements);

            for (i=0; i<top->numOfElements; i++)
            {
                printf("%s ", top->pElements[i].name);
            }
            printf("\n");

        printList(top->next);
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct list *top=NULL;
    char firstLine[200];
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    fp=openFile(fp);

        fgets(firstLine, 200, fp); /* in order to jump the 1st line */

            while (!feof(fp))
            {
                top=insertAsLast(top, fp);
            }
    fclose (fp);

    printList(top);

    return 0;
}
```

anyone is able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by the ID stored in the array temporarily.

```
static int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = (*(struct list**)a)->id;
    int y = (*(struct list**)b)->id;
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}
void printListOrderdByID(struct list *top){
    struct list **table, *p;
    size_t size=16, n=0, i;
    table = malloc(size*sizeof(struct list*));
    //Can be secured in the malloc simply if you use it the number of elements already known from a reading from a file.
    for(p=top; p ; p=p->next){
        table[n++] = p;
        if(n == size)
            table = realloc(table, (size+=16)*sizeof(struct list*));
    }
    qsort(table, n, sizeof *table, cmp);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int j;
        p = table[i];
        printf("%s %d %d ", p->name, p->id, p->numOfElements);
        for (j=0; j<p->numOfElements; j++){
            printf("%s ", p->pElements[j].name);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(table);
}
```

Comment: please could you explain what is
<code>
static int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = (*(struct list**)a)->id;
    int y = (*(struct list**)b)->id;
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}</code>

Thank you

Comment: @Mariadegregorio elements of the array passed a pointer to the element as a `void *` to comparison function that is used in `qsort`. So `(struct list**)a` is `const void *a` --> `struct list **`, `*` is `struct list **` --> `struct list *`.

Comment: @Mariadegregorio comparison function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to,
or greater than the second.

Comment: sorry and If I would like to order the list and then use the normal "printList"?

Comment: of course... as I did in my code...

I was asking if it woule be easy to 
-order the list by ID
-use printList(top);

As I'm really newbe with programming, I think your code is a little bit hard for me...

I'll try to study it later, right now I'm not at home :(

Thank you for your support and your answers.
Have a nice weekend. :D

Comment: @Mariadegregorio You need to sort the list itself to print using the `printList` in the order of `ID`. E.g `sort(&top);printList(top);`